# NullInjectorError: No provider for TranslateService in dependency

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

I created a custom Angular Library which uses TranslateModule as a dependency. When i use this library inside my main application as a NPM dependency, my application compile correctly, but the components inside my custom library throw the following error:

```
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[TranslateService -> TranslateService -> TranslateService]: NullInjectorError: No provider for TranslateService!
```

and don't show up.

When i use the library directly after compiling it on my computer an copying the dist folder inside the node_modules of my project, the error dissapears, it only appears when i install it through npm

Where could it come from?

Comment: Did you import the `TranslateModule` in your `app.module.ts`?

Comment: Yes i did,  ` imports[TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useClass: WebpackTranslateLoader,
      },
    }),]`

Comment: Add that ```providers: [TranslateService]```

Comment: Without you sharing more code snippets of your application we're not able to help your

Answer (score 0):

As [documentation](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core) :

first you should import TranslateModule in your app.module.ts

```
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {TranslateModule} from '@ngx-translate/core';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        TranslateModule.forRoot()
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

or if you use a SharedModule

```
@NgModule({
    exports: [
        CommonModule,
        TranslateModule
    ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```